# C++ compile error - no match for ‘operator=’

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment

The following code compiles without problem

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass() { std::cout << "Default Constructor!" << std::endl; }
  MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& m) { std::cout << "Copy assignment operator!" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass a;
  MyClass d;
  d = MyClass(a);
}
```

but when I change assignment operator argument to be non-const compiler prints error:

```
MyClass& operator=(MyClass& m) { std::cout << "Copy assignment operator!" << std::endl; }

error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘MyClass’ and ‘MyClass’)
```

I want to know the reason. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the `MyClass&` makes your `operator=` without `const` not a proper assignment operator. It must be `operator=(const MyClass&)` (or `operator=(MyClass)` but don't do that unless you know what you are doing, copy-&-swap...).

Otherwise, your code `d = MyClass(a)` cannot compile because a non-const reference will not bind to a temporary (r-value) such as `MyClass(a)`.

Note that, even without the `const`, a code such as `d = a` *will* compile, because the `a` is not an *r-value*. However, it is still not a proper assignment operator.

Comment: _"Note that, even without the const, a code such as d = a will compile ..."_ [It doesn't](http://ideone.com/Zl9I9e).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Actually, [it does](http://ideone.com/K0AcZR), you didn't write `d = a` but `d = MyClass(a)`

Comment: @rodrigo Sorry, you're right of course, I didn't spot the OP used a copy constructor there.

Comment: But I don't understand, if it is wrong to write operator= without const argument why compiler doesn't print error (without line d = MyClass(a))? Is there any case when the assignment operator without const argument can be used.

Comment: @AshotKhachatryan: It is not technically wrong: it is a valid member function, and a valid operator `=` overload, it is just not **the** assignment operator, because that has the extra `const` requirement.

Comment: `operator=(MyClass&)` _is_ a copy assignment operator alright (as are `operator=(MyClass)`, `operator=(MyClass const&)`, `operator=(MyClass volatile&)`, and `operator=(MyClass const volatile&)`)